# How to count total of specific column in a table

Tags: c#, .net, linq, count

I'm trying to count the *Total* amount of *Weight* in a certain column.

I've tried the following coding, but I only seem to get the first row's value and not the rest.

```
int QuoteId = (from x in db.Quotes where x.Id != null orderby x.Id descending select x.Id).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
var item = db.QuoteItems.Where(x => x.QuoteId == QuoteId).First();
QuoteItemSectionGroup quoteItemList = new QuoteItemSectionGroup();
foreach (var quoteItem in db.QuoteItemSectionGroups.Where(x => x.QuoteItemId == item.Id).ToList())
{
    var total = new QuoteItemSectionGroup
    {
        Weight = quoteItem.Weight
    };
    quoteItemList.Weight = total.Weight;
}
```

So my question is: How can I count the total amount of the *Weight* column in my table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You obviously want to add the current number to the `Weigth` you already obtained, don´t you? Furtheremore you won´t need to create a new instance of `QuoteItemSectionGroup` only for the sake of setting its `Weight`-property temporarily.

```
foreach (var quoteItem in db.QuoteItemSectionGroups.Where(x => x.QuoteItemId == item.Id).ToList())
{
    quoteItemList.Weight += quoteItem.Weight;  // pay attention on the + before the equality-character
}
```

The `+=` operator in `x += 1` is simply a shortcut for `x = x + 1`.

Or even simpler using Linq [`Sum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534734%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)-method

```
var totalWeight = db.QuoteItemSectionGroups
    .Where(x => x.QuoteItemId == item.Id)
    .Sum(x => x.Weight);
```

EDIT: Furthermore you can simplify your code a bit so it finally becomes this:

```
var item = db.Quotes.Where(x => x.Id != null)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
    .FirstOrDefault();
var totalWeight = db.QuoteItemSectionGroups
    .Where(x => x.QuoteItemId == item.Id)
    .Sum(x => x.Weight);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer man. I'm not clued up to most of the c# theory, but can you give me a basic explanation on how the `+` before the `=` works?

Comment: Brilliant! The second one is great.

Comment: @CareTaker22 the syntax += is not a theory of c#, but it works in most languages. Its a short cut for `variable = variable + value // (varariable += value)`